# Angular 12 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length') at HttpHeaders.applyUpdate

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs, httpclient

I'm getting this error message when I make a http request in my Angular Service. This only happens when I logout but when I login the error disappears:

Here's my authentication Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

export interface ServerResponse {
  success: boolean;
  msg: string;
  user: any;
  token: any
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {

    authToken: any;
  user: any;
    public baseUri: string = 'http://localhost:3000/users';
    public headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public registerUser(user): Observable<ServerResponse> {
    return this.http.post<ServerResponse>(this.baseUri + '/register', user, { headers: this.headers });
  }

  public authenticateUser(user): Observable<ServerResponse> {
    return this.http.post<ServerResponse>(this.baseUri + '/authenticate', user, { headers: this.headers });
  }

  public getProfile(): Observable<ServerResponse> {
    this.loadToken();
    const head = this.headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    return this.http.get<ServerResponse>(this.baseUri + '/profile', { headers: head });
  }

  public storeUserData(token, user) {
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.authToken = token;
    this.user = user;
  }

  public loadToken() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    this.authToken = token;
  }

  public loggedin() {
    if (localStorage.id_token == undefined ){
      return false;
    } else {
      const helper = new JwtHelperService();
      return !helper.isTokenExpired(localStorage.id_token);
    }
  }

  public logout() {
    this.authToken = null;
    this.user = null;
    localStorage.clear();
  }
}
```

This is what my logout function looks like in my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../Services/auth.service';
import { PostService } from "../Services/post.service";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
//declare var anime: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  public isMenuCollapsed = true;
  username;
  postAuthor: string;
  posts: any;

  constructor(
    public authService: AuthService,
    private flashMessage: FlashMessagesService,
    private postService: PostService,
    private router: Router) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {}

onLogoutClick() {
    this.authService.logout();
    this.flashMessage.show('You are logged out', {cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 2000});
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

The error logs look like this:

```
core.js:6456 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')
    at HttpHeaders.applyUpdate (http.js:236)
    at http.js:208
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HttpHeaders.init (http.js:208)
    at HttpHeaders.forEach (http.js:271)
    at Observable._subscribe (http.js:1713)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
    at innerSubscribe (innerSubscribe.js:67)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:57)
```

I can't figure out why this error is happening. Even though everything seems to be working fine. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank You Very Much.

Comment: pls share the error logs as well

Comment: I just posted the error log.

Comment: which api call is giving this error ? and i can see there is no api call while calling `logout`. can u tell when exactly u are getting this error ?

Comment: I get this error when I'm logged out of my service. The moment I hit the logout button, this error occurs. I'm calling my logout and login service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I am seeing in error and if you see the error as well it is pointing towards your HttpHeaders. The problem is you are setting your token to null on logout. Now it is for this reason you get this error only when you are logged out and not when logged in (because token is present at while you are logged in).

Set the header only if token is available. Try the following:

```
if(token) { then set your header only }
```

Comment: Thank You for the reply. Could you please tell me where I should use this if statement. Inside my logout function?

Comment: Not in your logOut but where you are appending the head (its loadToken I think, where-ever token is being passed).  Just append it only if token is not null. First do that if still there is some issue drop a message.

Comment: @WahabShah I'd assume in your `getProfile` method, it's where you append a token to your headers.